# How to get the allowed currency names (NOT CURRENCY CODE) for a store

Tags: magento2

I want to get the list of allowed currency names for a store. 
Please note that, I know how to get the allowed currency codes, but all I want is , it's name.
For example, Indian Rupee, US Dollar etc.

Please suggest some code without using the Object Manager concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface;



protected $storeManager;

protected $localeCurrency;


public function __construct(
    ...
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;    
    $this->localeCurrency = $localeCurrency;
    ....
}


$currencyCodes=$this->storeManager->getStore(1)->getAvailableCurrencyCodes(); // replace with your store Id
if($currencyCodes){
    foreach ($currencyCodes as $code){
        $currencyData[$code]=$this->localeCurrency->getCurrency($code)->getName();
    }
    print_r($currencyData);exit;
}
```

I know `foreach` loop is bad to prepare array but I think there is no direct method available to get the currency name, even Magento team does the `forech` loop to print the currency name. You can also confirm this in

`app\code\Magento\Sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\create\data.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

Get currency codes and names

```
protected $storeManager;
protected $currencyInterface;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface $currencyInterface
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->currencyInterface = $currencyInterface;
}


$availableCurrencies = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getAvailableCurrencyCodes();
$currencyNames = array();

foreach ($availableCurrencies as $currencyCode) {
    $currencyNames[] = $this->currencyInterface->getCurrency($currencyCode)->getName();
}

print_r($currencyNames);
```

Comment: `getOptionCurrencies` will display all currency name not only allowed currency @Dinesh